# Angular2 Observable - Subscription data is undefined, but Browser Debug shows otherwise

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, subscription

As per title - when subscribing to data from a service call, the data set is returned as 'undefined'.

However, debugging the code via the browser shows there is indeed the correct data present from the subscription. Here is an example of the code, any ideas what I may be overlooking are appreciated.

```
this.userService.getUserTypes().subscribe(data => {
    console.log('data length is ' + data.result.length);
});
```

Comment: Can you show us `getUserTypes()`?

Answer (score -1):

You are using a subscription. Which means that data may not exist right away. So therefore .length won't always work. Try:

```
if (data) {
     console.log('data length is ' + data.result.length);
}
```

Comment: The subscription will only fire when the observable emits. So as long as `length` exists when the observable fires, it'll be there, and that has nothing to do with the observable.